# Can't Display Wordpress Custom Fields from JSON Response in Sencha App (likely easy)

Tags: json, wordpress, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm using Sencha Architect and I'm trying to get the custom field values from this JSON response created with the Wordpress JSON API:

[JSON Response](http://theojai.net/?json=get_recent_posts&post_type=deals&custom_fields=wpcf-deal-business-owner,wpcf-deal-expiry,wpcf-deal-rules)

I've created a model, but I'm just not sure what to type in the "Mapping" fields for each of those custom_fields in the JSON response. 
Any thoughts?

Here is my Sencha model.  What do I put in the mapping areas for the last three?:

```
Ext.define('Ojai.model.Deal', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'Title',
                mapping: 'title'
            },
            {
                name: 'Business',
                mapping: 'custom_fields.wpcf-deal-business-owner'
            },
            {
                name: 'Expiry',
                mapping: 'wpcf-deal-expiry'
            },
            {
                name: 'Terms',
                mapping: 'wpcf-deal-rules'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: your link is broken please correct it, for instance select the text "JSON response", click the hyperlink icon and paste the url into the modal window.

Comment: Hi Dreen, link has been fixed, and tested.  It's working.  Thanks for noticing.